# Assigning empty array

Tags: excel, vba

Just wondering.
Is this not supported in excel 2019?
`dim arr as variant: arr = array()`
It works normally in excel 2016 but in 2019 it assigns error, so I can't do ubound(arr).
Am I wrong?

Actually more specific is like this within property QSELECTLIST:

```
Dim list As Variant, partlist As Variant
list = Array(): partlist = Array()
...
QSELECTLIST = Array(list, partlist)
```

With tracer "list" and "partlist" will show 'invalid procedure call or argument'.
QSELECTLIST is then 'Empty'.
So I can't assign this property to variant variable because it will throw an error.

This on the other hand works:

```
Sub test()
Dim list As Variant, partlist As Variant, cn As Variant
list = Array(""): partlist = Array("")

cn = Array(list, partlist)
End Sub
```

So basically I can't set empty stacked array in excel 2019... this is so weird.

Comment: When I try your code here (office 365), the error message occurs on `QSELECTLIST = Array(list, partlist)`.  No problem defining the empty arrays `list` and `partlist`.  creating an array of empty arrays fails.  I don't have 2016 for testing.

Comment: I apparently asked duplicate question and it's excel bug.